# List docker containers including full container id instead of short one

Tags: docker

I know I can get the full container id using `docker inspect --format "{{.ID}}" [container name]`
I want to have the full container ID during container listing, not scripting looping one by one.

There is no way out other than scripting it myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--no-trunc` (Don't truncate output).

`docker ps --no-trunc`

If you want the ID only, use `docker ps --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}"`

Comment: There we go, I would settle with `docker ps --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}"
`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```bash
  containerName="container-name" 
  containerID=$(docker ps -aq --filter="NAME=$containerName")
  echo containerID
```

Comment: For me this returns the short ID as well - ex: `f9e5bd850d95`